# Survey Monkey Web Survey assistance

Tags: surveymonkey

I would first like to say I am totally oblivious to the programming world.  That being said, I have what is probably a very simple question to answer.  I have built a SurveyMonkey survey with a "ranking" type  question.  There are 14 items in this ranking so it is already a difficult question to digest.  However, SurveyMonkey makes it even more difficult by re-ordering each answer choice after a ranking is picked.  For example, lets say I have answers listed in the order A,B,C,D and I want to rank them 1,3,4,2.  When I change the ranking of answer B to 3 it reorders the answers to A,C,B,D.  I DON'T want this to happen, as I mentioned there are 14 items in the question and re-ordering the answers just makes it impossible.  HELP!

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to change the behavior of the ranking question. Its behavior is discussed in SurveyMonkey's help documents here: http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Ranking-Question-is-Automatically-Ordering-Answers

The question type you're looking for is a matrix question with forced ranking: http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Matrix-Question Look under the heading "Forced Ranking (one response per column)"